Which of these two ways is the correct one for using VLOOKUP?
This is a question to give an end to a discussion between me and the rest of my work friends, since we use the VLOOKUP formula differently. Can anyone help us?
Basically, when I use this formula, my first element, equivalent to the search_value, is always the column that has the values ​​I'm looking for, for example:
=VLOOKUP(@A:A;Test!A:A;1;FALSE)
In comparison, my coworkers only use the column row value, like this:
=VLOOKUP(A2;Test!A:A;1;FALSE)
They argue with me that my formula is a "gimmick" that shouldn't work, but it does. I think my formula makes perfect sense and is coherent. I also believe that it works because of the @ in front of the column, but I don't have enough technical knowledge to say what this does exactly.
Is my way wrong? Is it a "workaround" or is it also correct and makes sense?
Both ways results in the same values, so I don't know what to think :/

@A:A is equal to current row of range A:A. Which is more dynamical than A2, but it's the same differently  @ means intersection.

Welcome! Also in Microsoft 365 we could use spill ranges without fill-down so VLOOKUP(array/range,Sheet2!A:A,1) is also worth considering.

The @ sign is the implicit intersection operator, which basically returns the value from the row or column that matches the location of the formula.
The main drawback of using @ is that it explicitly uses the same row as the formula, whereas a dynamic reference like A2 can be used from any cell (meaning the formula doesn't have to be in row 2 of the formula column if you want the value from row 2 of the input column)
Personally, I would use the exact reference (A2) and rely on copy/paste to adjust the reference for each row of the VLOOKUP.  But newer Excel users that are taught these newer methods may disagree.  I often replace the implicit intersection with an exact reference when Excel uses them automatically when referencing table data. Table references (e.g. Table1[@[Date]]don't change when copied orthogonally - they always reference the same column, which is annoying when I reference a cell and expect the relative reference to change when I copy in either direction.
Bottom line - neither is "wrong" - they are two different ways to do the same thing.
